# Import error while doing import tensorflow as tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have installed tensorflow for GPU using native pip [using native pip to install tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_native_pip)

While I use import tensorflow as tf with python3,

**ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I don't know how to solve this. Please help. I have crawling through google and stack overflow! I am using ubuntu17.04!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing nvidia cuda or some parts of it.
This error says that it can't find a lib called libcublas.so.8.0 wich is part of nvidias cuda.
I don't know which Linux you have but if it is debian/ubuntu related you can try to install cuda like this:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev  nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

You also probably need this:

```
sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev
```

Note that you can also build tensorflow without GPU support see: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources